# Multi-color Safari Pinned Tab Favicon

Tags: safari

How do I make my Safari Pinned Tab Favicon multi-colored like Pandora has? 
My logo and favicon are three colors.
I followed this tutorial to get the red svg I currently have, but it's a few years old.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html

Thanks!

Jason

[image: Safari]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: If you go to http://pandora.com/favicon.ico you can save the actual favicon to your local Mac, open it in your image editor of choice and see what they did, if not how...

Comment: @SteveChambers Apple has a special pinned tab favicon in .svg format. The .ico format is what I used for other browsers.

Comment: Cool, just learned something. is it favicon.svg?

Comment: @SteveChambers

It needs to be formatted right. From the link I provided above: <link rel="mask-icon" href="website_icon.svg" color="red">

Answer (score 2):

Today I rebooted my iMac and when I opened Safari, the pinned tab icons are now multi-colored. It looks like Safari is now pulling the .ico file that the other browsers are pulling. Problem solved.

[image]

Comment: Well, that only worked for about a day.
Back to solid red.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide an svg file linked in the header, Safari will use that for the pinned tab icon, and at least on my version (13.1.2), also for the regular tab icon.

If you don't provide one, Safari uses favicon.ico instead, so there you can have multiple colors.  My favicon.ico has 16, 24, 32, 48, and 64 px; it's using one of the first three, not sure which.  I would have to make a favicon.ico where those sizes have distinct graphics to tell.

And getting rid of the svg is one less file and header line to deal with.  I don't know what the point of it is.